# How to iterate JSON object with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to iterate this kind of JSON:

```
{
  "object": {
    "array1": {
      "id": 1
    },
    "array2": {
      "id": 2
    }
  }
}
```

I've attempted to use this:

```
for (var i in dictionary) {
  console.log(dictionary[i].id);
}
```

but doesn't work.

Comment: Do people not read documentation and tutorials anymore? https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jzxe1a6b/

Comment: @epascarello Reopening because it is clear now.

Comment: @Craig If that's the case, if you suspect, I am very well happy to vote to delete this question. But the OP has lot more questions, that's been discussed below. Check the discussion below.

Comment: @Craig Voted to delete. Happy now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I've searched everywhere and can't find an answer that I want.* Seriously? Didn't see what [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) does?

> A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via their named properties.

```js
var arr = {
  "object": {
    "array1": {
      "id": 1
    },
    "array2": {
      "id": 2
    }
  }
};
$.each(arr, function (i, v) {
  console.log(i);
  console.log(v);
  $.each(v, function (idx, val) {
    console.log(idx);
    console.log(val);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**AJAX**

If you are using AJAX to fetch the JSON, you can very well use: `$.getJSON`:

```js
$.getJSON("https://cdn.rawgit.com/fge/sample-json-schemas/master/avro/avro-schema.json", function (res) {
  $.each(res, function (i, v) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(v);
    if (typeof v == "object")
    $.each(v, function (idx, val) {
      console.log(idx);
      console.log(val);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yours works, @Craigs doesn't.

Comment: I'll accept when I can.

Comment: @decryptable Thanks.

Comment: @Craig Nopes, I reopened because it is clear now.

Comment: @Craig I have added that in the question's comment as well.

Comment: How do I get the name of the array e.g `array1`

Comment: The `key` of the loop has the information. The function takes two arguments, `index, value`. The `index` is what you need to look at.

Comment: Okay. I'll give it a go.

Comment: @decryptable Sure...

Answer (score -1):

```
var objectData = {
  "object": {
    "array1": {
      "id": 1
    },
    "array2": {
      "id": 2
    }
  }
};

$.each(objectData, function(key, data){
    // Do stuff here
});
```

To use this with json from a URL:

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
       $.each(json, function(key, data){
           console.log(key);
           console.log(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll give this one a go.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it

Comment: @Craig why don't you give an explanation of what it does?

Comment: Because its clear that it is doing "each - objectData" with a key and data value?

Comment: How do I got by this if I'm pulling the JSON from a URL?

Comment: @decryptable Use `$.getJSON`.

Comment: I've commented how to get it form a URL and use it. Please accept if it works for you :)

Comment: Let me test it and I'll get back to you

Comment: The only reason mine didnt was the variable was slightly wrong, obvious with a quick scan of the code!

Answer (score -1):

try the following

```
var d={
  "object": {
    "array1": {
      "id": 1
    },
    "array2": {
      "id": 2
    }
  }
}

$.each(d,function(i,v){console.log(i,v)})
```

Comment: Another LQ answer without any explanation. Worse than the previous two answers.